# Should I first collect the files and then execute a task or should I execute tasks while collecting?)

Tags: java, file, io

I need to go through all files of a given folder (and its sub folders) and execute something on each file.
I was looking for a way to go through all the files recursively and found one solution in Apache Commons Io:
FileUtils.iterateFiles
It returns an iterator.
I checked how its implemented and saw that it goes through all the files and adds them to a collection, then returns an iterator for the collection. 
Well sure that's what it does. that's what I was looking for :)

But then I thought - is it effective to first collect all the files and then loop through all of them and perform what I want?
Or should I instead of collection them, just perform the action in the recursive traverse?

Should be noted that my required actions on the files include IO manipulations on them, which might fail.. (which can be handled in both ways.. but just noted in case I'm missing something in my line of thought)
Also, the set of folders&files I'm traversing MAY reach 400 folders or 5000 files or so, and file sizes may reach few gigas (again, not so relevant when just traversing through the files but relevant because I intend to perform IO tasks)..

Any thoughts?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should start navigating on the filesystem, create a Runnable/Callable implementation to what you would like to do with these files and fore every file found submit it to a ThreadPool (you can create one from the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class).

In this case you should probably use a fixed thread pool and the size may vary, you should benchmark and see how the amount of threads working on your files affect performance.

Comment: Well actually my original intent was not to do this multi threaded.
I wanted to go through the files and synchronously perform something on each file. My question is regarding when to perform what I want - while iterating the folder tree? Or first iterate the folder tree, collect all files and then go through all the files i've collected and perform that I want.
BUT the multi threaded issue is a good thought. Does it add anything here to perform the tasks in multiple thread, taking into account that the tasks involve IO to/from the disk?

Comment: That depends. Are the files large? What kind of operation are you performing? Can you cache the file contents in memory and process them  when possible? There are many variables here.

Comment: What apache's iterateFiles does is not to cache the contents in the memory. it gives a collection of all File objects.
File sizes can vary.. some can be few MB others can be few GIGAS

Comment: It's up to you to decide then, there is no single answer for this. If the process you run on the file more processor intensive than IO intensive, going multi-thread might be a better option. You should try, benchmark and make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Reading things from disk is slow and expensive. The best approach is to use multithread so you don't waste time on waiting for IO to give back the file contents. As soon as file read is sent, the read/write thread goes to sleep for certain time and another thread will process what you need to do. once the read/write thread wakes up, it writes to the disk.

To answer your question, it's not possible to load all files(and their contents) all once and continue to process them due to memory constrain. Using multithread to process a few files in once. or you can use mapreduce, depends on the given task

Comment: 1. I didnt mean to load all files at once. I ment collecting the paths to the files and then after I collect all the paths, go through the collection, In contrary to not collection the paths, but exceuting what I want while traversing the tree for the first time..
2. Can you elaborate on how this can be done with mapreduce? the tasks include duplicating files and modifying files (different types of files so different kinds of tasks..). I'm a bit familiar with mapreduce but not quite to the level I can implement what I need..

Comment: I see. I will still avoid to collect all filenames first personally. It's just an additional operation which doesn't give you any advantage.

MapReduce might not suit your case then, unless you "abuse" the usage. :)

Answer (score 0):

This probably depends on how large the list is. If it is not a problem keeping the list in memory then I would complete the list before working on files.
Reason is quite simple: on one side scanning the directory tree is usually fast because of file system organization; on the second side you should probably work sequentially on one file at a time in order to achieve better performance (if you are multitasking and work on many files concurrently then your disk will slow down).